# How to make sure Images are loaded in a loop and in correct order

Tags: javascript

I am loading images from remote server.
how do i make sure that all images are loaded in correct order

also how do i make sure the alert is called only when all images are loaded

the below code does not load the images in correct order  and calls the alert  before the images are loaded.

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $('.fancybox').each(function () {
    var hh = $(this).attr('href');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = hh;

    function TIMG(i) {
      if (img.complete != null && img.complete == true) {
        $('.mag').append('<img src="' + hh + '" class="cls" />');
      } else {
        setTimeout(TIMG, 1000);
      }
    }

    setTimeout(TIMG, 1000);    
  });

  alert(hi);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to append an image each second (when available) or are you trying to append the images as soon as they are available, but in the proper order?

Comment: I am trying to append as soon as they are available but in correct order

Comment: WHY do you take 7 hrs to respond to clarifying questions.  It's simply wasteful of a lot of people's time and dramatically reduces the likeliness that you will get useful answers if you post a question and then disappear for 7 hours when we have questions about what you want.  You should understand that >90% of your question viewers are going to be in the first hour or so.  If you aren't around in that time to clarify questions, you give up most of your chance of getting multiple people to respond and those of us who do respond just get frustrated with you.

Comment: As it is, I had to rewrite my answer because you were not clear in your question when you wanted the images loaded and did not respond to a clarifying question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the new information that you just want to add them in order as soon as they are ready, you can do that like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      // preload all the images as fast as possible
      var imgs = [];
      $('.fancybox').each(function () {
          // get all images preloading immediately
          // so there is the best chance they are available when needed
          var img = new Image();
          imgs.push(img);
          img.onload = function() {
              addReadyImages();
          }
          img.className = "cls";
          img.src = $(this).attr('href');
      });

      function addReadyImages() {
          // show all images that are ready up to here
          while (imgs.length && imgs[0].complete === true) {
              // append the loaded image from the start of the array
              $('.mag').first().append(imgs[0]);
              // remove the one we just did from the start of the array
              imgs.shift();
          }
      }
 });
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sCHws/

This algorithm works as follows:

1. Start preloading all the images as soon as possible.
2. Store the image objects in an array in the order that the `.fancybox` items are encountered in your page
3. Set an onload handler for each image so we know immediately when it's ready
4. In the onload handler for any image, append all images at the front of the array that are ready and then remove them from the array

P.S. I've assumed there is only one `.mag` item and thus we don't need to make separate copies of the image objects (much more efficient that way - rather than creating new image objects).  If that is not the case, then please disclose your HTML so we can see the whole problem.

Comment: @skcrpk - it does load in the order that `.fancybox` items are encountered.  I've also rewritten the code to display them as soon as possible and not use timers.

Comment: i tested the code but it does not load the images in correct order , I want the images to load in the same order as they are encountered by the loop , like the first image in .fancybox should be appended to .mag and  then the second and so on

Comment: @skcrpk - it seems to work fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sCHws/.  You may need to show your actual code to understand why your implementation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since browsers will normally not block when downloading images,the only way to ensure that the images are loaded in the right order would be to load them serially...using a queue and then only beginning the next after the previous has completed.   That is definitely not recommended though since that could easily create a severe performance hit.

Waiting for when all of the images are loaded would likely best be done by the `.promise()` and related methods in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/promise/, and watching for when the images are `load()`ed.  If you particularly want to control the display of images (which is more likely what you'd be concerned with), then they could be displayed in sequence after they are loaded.